# How to replace content with a string? shell

Tags: php, shell, sed

I have made mistake. At first, i did not choose a DB log in independent page. Now 374 php pages with DB log in code. These pages in my linux server at the same direct.

Some pages with log in DB pages code:

```
try
{
    $conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=hpc' , 'xxx' , 'xxx');
}
 catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "connect failed!".$e->getMesage();
    exit;
}
```

Some pages with log in DB pagas code:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=hpc' , 'xxx' , 'xxx');
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);
```

Now I want use only one DB.php to take over them with include("DB.php"); I have tried:

```
sed -i "/^try/^}$/,s/.*/include(\"DB.php\")/"g" *
```

and

```
sed -i "/^conn/true)\;$/,s/.*/include(\"DB.php\")/g *
```

But they failed. I know take over string using sed: `sed -i "s/A/B/g" *`.But I don't know how to replace content to a string.Who can help me ?

Comment: When you only want to replace these blocks with "PDO" in it  (completely?) and don't want to replace others, you must carefully define your requirements. Do we have to replace something starting with `try` (and replace 9 lines with the one line with include) or do we have to look around from lines which have `new PDO` in it ?

Comment: Is the the second `Some pages...` block your expected output or something else? If it is your expected output then explain the transformation, If it's not then clarify what it is and add your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I do not misunderstand, a **sed** solution could be

```
// replace try-catch block  
sed -i '/^try/{:t;N;/exit;\n}$/!bt;s/.*/include("DB\.php");/}' *

// replace your second pattern
sed -i '/\$conn/{N;/true/s/.*/include("DB\.php");/}' *
```